# Q_OBJECT causing a 'undefined reference to v_table' issue

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject, moc

I have successfully created a GUI in `C++` using `Qt` in Eclipse, but then when it came to assigning my own button click event, I was told the macro `Q_OBJECT` would need to be included in the headerfile of my `QWidget` class.

Upon running, the window no longer displays and I am met with an error on both the constructor and the destructor of my `QWidget` class.

The header file is as follows:

```
#ifndef MEDIAPLAYERWIZARD_H_
#define MEDIAPLAYERWIZARD_H_

#include "../MediaPlayer.Helpers/SystemConfiguration.h"
#include "../MediaPlayer.Helpers/StringHelpers.h"
#include "../MediaPlayer.DataAccess/DataRepository.h"
#include "../MediaPlayer.Helpers/Globals.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class MediaPlayerWizard: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MediaPlayerWizard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void Initialize();
    virtual ~MediaPlayerWizard();

private:
    QLabel *lblWelcomeMessage;

    //Input
    QLineEdit *txtName;
    QLabel *lblName;

    QLineEdit *txtActivationCode;
    QLabel *lblActivationCode;

    //Buttons
    QPushButton *btnActivate;
    QPushButton *btnCancel;

    //Layouts
    QVBoxLayout *fldWizardLayout;

    QHBoxLayout *fldWelcomeMessage;
    QHBoxLayout *fldName;
    QHBoxLayout *fldActivationCode;
    QHBoxLayout *fldButtons;

private slots:
    void btnActivateClicked();
};

#endif /* MEDIAPLAYERWIZARD_H_ */
```

And the constructor and destructors are as follows:

```
MediaPlayerWizard::MediaPlayerWizard(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    Initialize(); //Instantiates the buttons and labels etc..
}

MediaPlayerWizard::~MediaPlayerWizard(){

}
```

All of my header files are listed in the `HEADERS` list of my .pro file, and I have ran `QMake` after adding the `Q_OBJECT` macro to my header file.

Initialize code:

```
void MediaPlayerWizard::Initialize()
{
    //Widget Configuration

    this->setWindowTitle("Media Player: First Run Wizard");

    int labelWidth = 150;

    //Welcome Message
    lblWelcomeMessage = new QLabel;
    lblWelcomeMessage->setText("Welcome to the first run wizard that will assist you in\n connecting and registering this advertising player to your account.");
    lblWelcomeMessage->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    //Input Labels
    lblName = new QLabel;
    lblName->setText("Name: ");
    lblName->setFixedWidth(labelWidth);

    lblActivationCode = new QLabel;
    lblActivationCode->setText("Application Code: ");
    lblActivationCode->setFixedWidth(labelWidth);

    //Input Fields
    txtName = new QLineEdit();
    txtActivationCode = new QLineEdit();

    //Buttons
    btnActivate = new QPushButton;
    btnActivate->setText("Activate");
    btnCancel = new QPushButton;
    btnCancel->setText("Cancel");

    //Button Events
    QObject::connect(btnActivate, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btnActivateClicked()));
    QObject::connect(btnCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    //Layouts
    fldWelcomeMessage = new QHBoxLayout;
    fldWelcomeMessage->addWidget(lblWelcomeMessage);

    fldName = new QHBoxLayout;
    fldName->addWidget(lblName);
    fldName->addWidget(txtName);

    fldActivationCode = new QHBoxLayout;
    fldActivationCode->addWidget(lblActivationCode);
    fldActivationCode->addWidget(txtActivationCode);

    fldButtons = new QHBoxLayout;
    fldButtons->addWidget(btnActivate);
    fldButtons->addWidget(btnCancel);

    fldWizardLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    fldWizardLayout->addLayout(fldWelcomeMessage);
    fldWizardLayout->addLayout(fldName);
    fldWizardLayout->addLayout(fldActivationCode);
    fldWizardLayout->addLayout(fldButtons);

    setLayout(fldWizardLayout);
    show();
}
```

Here is the error message displayed:

```
Building target: MediaPlayerCPP
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib -o "MediaPlayerCPP"  ./src/MediaPlayer.o ./src/MediaPlayerWizard.o ./src/mysqlapidemo.o  ./MediaPlayer.Services/MediaPlayerClient.o  ./MediaPlayer.Helpers/DeviceManagement.o ./MediaPlayer.Helpers/Globals.o ./MediaPlayer.Helpers/MD5.o ./MediaPlayer.Helpers/StringHelpers.o ./MediaPlayer.Helpers/SystemConfiguration.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/DataObject.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/Database.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/Media.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/MediaLog.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/MediaLogProvider.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/MediaProvider.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/MediaSchedule.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/MediaScheduleProvider.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/SystemConfig.o ./MediaPlayer.DataAccess/SystemConfigProvider.o   -lQtCore -lmysqlclient -lz -lQtGui
./src/MediaPlayerWizard.o: In function `MediaPlayerWizard::MediaPlayerWizard(QWidget*)':
/home/gtteam/Projects/MediaPlayerCPP/Debug/../src/MediaPlayerWizard.cpp:10: undefined reference to `vtable for MediaPlayerWizard'
/home/gtteam/Projects/MediaPlayerCPP/Debug/../src/MediaPlayerWizard.cpp:10: undefined reference to `vtable for MediaPlayerWizard'
./src/MediaPlayerWizard.o: In function `MediaPlayerWizard::~MediaPlayerWizard()':
/home/gtteam/Projects/MediaPlayerCPP/Debug/../src/MediaPlayerWizard.cpp:77: undefined reference to `vtable for MediaPlayerWizard'
/home/gtteam/Projects/MediaPlayerCPP/Debug/../src/MediaPlayerWizard.cpp:77: undefined reference to `vtable for MediaPlayerWizard'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MediaPlayerCPP] Error 1
```

Comment: Please show the code for `Initialize()` function too.

Comment: upon running or upon compilation? Anyway clean your build directory , add the macro and build again.

Comment: Upon building the MediaPlayerWizard.cpp

Comment: Have you tried to run `qmake` manually before project building?

Comment: Yeah, tried with and tried without. Still the same error.

Comment: @GenericMadman clean your build directory. You specifically need to remove the file mediaplayerwizard_h.h before building again.

Comment: Please indicate where lines 10 and 77 in your .cpp file are.

Comment: @RobbieE The constructor and destructor for the class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark member function as a slot to use it as a slot.
So, try to change declaration

`void btnActivateClicked();`

with

`private slots:
void btnActivateClicked();`

or

`Q_SLOT void btnActivateClicked();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment `//Q_OBJECT` in mediaplayerwizard.h, the line should contain only `Q_OBJECT`

And define void `btnActivateClicked();` as slot.

Comment: I think you need to read the question again. And then once more.

Comment: his posted code contains this line commented out and he gets the error that he should add Q_OBJECT macro. Actually, usage of signals and slot requires defining of the Q_OBJECT in any case.

Comment: His problem is that when he adds the Q_OBJECT macro he has an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your build directory and build the solution again. Rebuild could not work so please remove the build directory. This is [an old Qt issue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/debug.html#common-bugs).

Comment: @GenericMadman can you ***cut the exact error message*** and paste here ? And are you sure the code shown above is what you are compiling?

Comment: I have added it to the bottom of the main post.

Comment: @GenericMadman As pointed by @Andrey `btnActivateClicked` is a `Q_SLOT`. Have you tried doing what he recommended and remove the build directory after that?

Comment: @JacobKrieg Yeah, I tried both methods, with no such luck.

Comment: @GenericMadman Where is the implementation for `btnActivateClicked`?
Did you implement it?

Comment: @JacobKrieg It is implemented in the cpp file, but only has `std::cout << "OnClick" << std::endl;`

Comment: @GenericMadman Can you update the code with the changes you've made?

Comment: @GenericMadman I can't figure it out, I think it would be best to upload the whole project so we could check it out if it's not something confidential. Or you could just strip the project as much as possible and keep the error...

Comment: I have pretty much shown you the whole project. Minus the main method instantiating and showing the mediaplayer qwidget.

Comment: So I took your code and did a test application and for me it works fine. I uploaded my project so you can make a comparison... http://www.fileshare.ro/e30893428. Can you please tell us if you're using `shadow build` for your project or not? If you're not using `shadow build` than the files are build generated in the same folder as the sources and it is possible that you didn't remove all the generated files. I really do recommend using `shadow build` for your project.